# How to implement a formula at the end of your loop in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, formula

I'm trying to essentially have a loop that counts certain criteria for me. At the end of my code I want to make it so that whatever is not counted is essentially called "DRSNR". I know I could use a simple formula in my file to make it work, but I'd rather have the formula in my VBA code so that it becomes dummy proof and no one erases it by mistake as I wont be the only user.

Now for some reason in my code doesn't work at this place:

```
drsnr = lastrow - sac - count
```

For some reason I always get the count of `0` no matter what. Any ideas? I first thought that my `lastrow` wasn't attributed as an integer, so I added `Dim lastrow as integer`, however that didn't seem to work either.

```
Sub DeleteSAC()
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim sac As Integer
    Dim drsnr As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer

    Sheets(1).Select

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    'have to keep data in a table for this to actually work as it ctrls+left to the table, which will end where the very last text of any row is
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    count = Sheet2.Cells(1, 7).Value
    sac = 0
    i = 2
    j = lastColumn

    For i = 2 To lastrow
    For j = lastColumn To 1 Step -1
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) = "SAC" Or Sheet1.Cells(i, j) = "Incorrect address" Then
        count = count - 1
        sac = sac + 1
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If
    Next j
    NextIteration:
    Next i

    Sheet2.Cells(1, 7) = count
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 10) = sac
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 13) = drsnr
    drsnr = lastrow - sac - count

    Sheets(2).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to move this line:

`drsnr = lastrow - sac - count`

before:

`Sheet2.Cells(1, 13) = drsnr`

`drsnr`will be an initialised `Integer` with value `0`, until you assign it some other value.

Comment: Works great! Thanks :)